# Swift 2.3 IndexPath error in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am somewhat new to iOS and swift. I recently switched to swift 2.3 and now I am getting this error

```
Use of undeclared type 'IndexPath'
```

for this method

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

Any Ideas??

Comment: @EricAya I tried that.

Comment: Function should be like this func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell

Comment: Seems to be something with swift 2.3 and swift 3.0 getting the syntax jumbled.

Answer (score 4):

The function parameter should be `NSIndexPath` not `IndexPath`. Xcode 8+ uses the documentation and code completion for `Swift 3.0`.

**Swift 2.3** syntax:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

**Swift 3.0** syntax:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: @Sanjeetverma was correct that the full method should look like this. `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

Yup! It's wrong in the Apple documentation. Not sure why they don't just fix it